# Copy all files in particular folder to maven package

Tags: maven

I have a maven project. When I execute **mvn package** I want to copy all files in a particular folder into the application package. For example, I have a folder **abcd** somewhere within my project and i want it to be copied during to the package. For this purpose, I have modified the **maven-war-plugin** in pom.xml to be as follows:

```
                      <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4</version>
                        <configuration>

                            <webResources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources/local</directory>
                                    <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>client_secrets.json</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>##CORRECT_PATH_TO_FOLDER##</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <targetPath>${project.build.directory}\project-name\##FOLDER_WHERE_I_WANT##</targetPath>
                                </resource>
                            </webResources>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
```

When I run this, I get that there was an **error copying the resource**. It shows me the correct folder path, but it gives me a build failure. I also checked that the folder exists and has proper permissions as well.

What may be wrong in this?

Comment: Does running it with `mvn package -x` (for debug) give you more info about the failure ?

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this?

Comment: I basically want to copy a set of files over at package time and I don't want to put it in resources folder.

Comment: One particular case which I want to use is to minify the javascript files at prepare-package time and then copy over the minified files in the application package, along with the files which were ignored to be minified

Comment: There is a plugin that do exactly that. http://samaxes.github.io/minify-maven-plugin/

Comment: i am using that plugin only. but i am ignoring a few files for that plugin. so i have to use the maven-war-plugin in order to package those files as well

Comment: Did you try to use _slashes_ instead of _backslashes_ in `<targetPath>`?